# Curvature of saddle by definition

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I'm trying to compute the principle curvatures of the saddle $M$ defined by $z= y^2 -x^2$ at the point $p = (0,0,0)$, but I know my computations are wrong.  Maybe you can help to see where I went wrong.

I have computed the tangent plane as $z = 0$.  So first take a vector $(0,1,0)= e_1$, corresponding to the $x=0$ part (so that $z = y^2$).  Now, define a map $\gamma(s) = (0,s,s^2)$.  Then, $\gamma : (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \rightarrow M$ and this satisfies $\gamma(0) = (0,0,0) = p$ and also $\gamma'(0) = (0,1,0) = e_1$.

Now, the first curvature should be the eigenvalue of the Weingarten map $L$.  That is by definition $$L(e_1) = -\frac{d}{ds}n(\gamma(s))|_{s=0}$$  But $$n(\gamma(s)) = \frac{\gamma(s)}{|\gamma(s)|} = \frac{(0,s,s^2)}{\sqrt{s^2+s^4}}$$

When I take the derivative and evaluate at $s= 0$, I get $(0,0,1)$, which is not a multiple of $e_1$.

I know by a different method that I should get $L(e_1) = 2e_1$.  Can you see where I went wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: For the Hyperbolic Parabola one has: K(u,v) = -4 at the origin and H(u,v) =  0  at the origin . 
From K = k1*k2 , H = 1/2( k1 + k2) , k1 = 2 , k2 = -2 . Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid
Link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalCurvatures.html

Comment: @Alan I know what the principal curvatures of this particular example are.  The point of this post is to figure out where I went wrong using the definition.

Comment: Sorry, I gathered that you were computing it in two different ways --  tried to add it to my edit, but stepped over the five minute limit.

Comment: Your mistake is that you confuse the map $n$ with normalization. In fact $n(\gamma(s))$ is the unitnormal field to $M$ at $\gamma(s)$, which is different from $\gamma(s)/|\gamma(s)$ (this is true at every point iff $M$ is a sphere).

Comment: @wspin I see!  How can we fix that then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the curve $\gamma(s) = (0,s,s^2)$. The tangent space $T_{\gamma(s)}M$ is spanned by the vectors $(1,0,0)$ and $\dot \gamma(s) = (0,1,2s)$. Hence a unitnormal field $n(s)$ along $\gamma$ is given by $$n(s) = (4s^2 + 1)^{-1/2}(0,2s,-1)$$
(it has length $1$ and is orthogonal to $(1,0,0)$ and $\dot \gamma(s)$). Thus for $e_1 = (0,1,0)$ (maybe a bad notation) the Weingarten map is
$$L(e_1) = -d/ds_{s = 0} n(s) =  (0,-2,0) = -2e_1.$$
The $-$ is a matter of choice of the sign of $n$.

Comment: Excellent thanks.